# Two dimensional sliders

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

I am controlling two values and visualizing the results in real time (pitch and roll angle of some object in 3D space). Currently I use Tkinter sliders for that. The problem is that I can only control one angle at a time. Is there any library offering two dimensional sliders where you hold the click and can move the cursor up/down/left/right to control two values simultaneously?

Comment: "Recommend a library" is off-topic for SO.  Search PyPI or elsewhere yourself.  Or write a class yourself based on a Canvas and an event handler for Motion events.  `http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html`.  Search `[tkinter] Motion event` for previous Q&A on SO.  To only track while left button is held down, bind the Motion tracker on Button-1 and untrack on ButtonRelease-1.

Comment: My question was not "Recommend a library" but "Does a library offering that exist or do I have to implement it by myself".